# how can i import and instantiate a class from a string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I  can  run these 2 lines fine but I want do do it with strings,

```
from envs.test_env import TestEnv
my_instance = TestEnv()
```

the file test_env.py is in the folder envs.  so envs/test_folder.py

I want to have string variables like:

```
path = "envs/test_env"
my_class_name = "TestEnv"
mod = __import__(path)
my_class = getattr(my_class_name,my_class_name)
my_instance = my_class()
```

The error I get is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'envs/test_env'
```

I saw there are some similar tickets, but mine seems different as I combine several different things.I want to import a file that is in a subdirectory and I have the class name and file name in strings.

Comment: """Docstring:
__import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0) -> module

Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python
interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module."""

Comment: Imports use directory names separated by dots, not slashes.

Comment: dots didnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the module into path.
Check my example below:

**Directory Structure**:

```
Current_Dir
    |
    |---qwerty.py
    |
    |---dinesh 
          |
          |--dsp.py -->> This file has class 'call_me'
```

**Code of dsp.py :**

```
class call_me(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        print("Dinesh")
```

**Code of qwerty.py:**

```
import sys
import os

lib_path = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'dinesh'
sys.path.insert(0,lib_path)

mod = __import__('dsp')
a = getattr(mod,'call_me')

s = a()
s.run()
```

**Output**

```
C:\Users\punddin\PycharmProjects\demo>python qwerty.py
Dinesh
```

========================================================================

Using `importlib`

```
import sys
import os
import importlib

lib_path = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'dinesh'
sys.path.insert(0,lib_path)

mod = importlib.import_module('dsp')
a = getattr(mod,'call_me')
s = a()
s.run()
```

Comment: this works,thanks! reading a comment from above, it says : """Docstring: __import__(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=(), level=0) -> module Import a module. Because this function is meant for use by the Python interpreter and not for general use it is better to use importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module."""  is there a way to do this with import_module as its the "proper" python way?